# XPATH - /a/text(), cant extract email address (text)

Tags: email, xpath, scrapy

I have simple HTML file with usernames and links to their sub-pages:

```
<a href="/user/someUserName@domain.com">someUserName@domain.com</a>
<a href="/user/someUserName">someUserName</a>
```

I use

```
xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
```

to extract user name in plain text.

I have a problem when user specifies username in form of email (see first example) - empty object in returned in such case.

Edit: I have just noticed html has changed recently and I haven't rechecked:
`<td><a href="/user/someUserName@domain.com"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="3f4d565c544c5e514bwer4rwre58525e5653115c5052">[email&#160;protected]</span></a></td>`

I'll extract from @href.

Comment: which programming language n module are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.
I'm extracting all other usernames without problem, there is only problem with email.

Comment: To be exact: using Scrapy framework:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code:-

```
import scrapy

inputString = '''<xmlData> 
                 <a href="/user/someUserName@domain.com">someUserName@domain.com</a>
                 <a href="/user/someUserName">someUserName</a>
                 </xmlData>'''

print scrapy.selector.Selector(text=inputString).xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
```

Output:-

```
someUserName@domain.com
```

Can you paste full python code? Because, xpath code seems working fine as:-

```
scrapy.selector.Selector(text=inputString).xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: I'm new to Python + new to Scrapy - I guess it makes rather weak combination...
I iterate through table with:
`for game in response.xpath('//tr')`
and then extract fields:
`user = game.xpath('.//td[5]/a/text()').extract_first()`
I can also see that when I have username: www.domain.com I only get www.domain as a result. Is this something about `.` `@` in the string?

Comment: Then, I would request you to paste the whole HTML source, which you are using along with the full python code.

Comment: Sorry, please check my last Edit in OP. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the text node children of an element (using `text()`) is generally discouraged, for exactly the reasons demonstrated here. With `<a>content</a>` you will get "content", with `<a><span>content</span><a>` you will get nothing, with `<a>h<sub>2</sub>o</a>` you will get two text nodes, "h" and "o".

Use string() to get the string value instead. The string value contains the concatenated content of all the descendant text nodes at any depth. ("content", "content", and "h2o" in these three examples).

Only reservation is that I don't know the Scrapy API so I don't know how it handles XPath expressions that return strings rather than nodes.